# Source not found during debugg

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, debugging

I have a simple code to write to a excel sheet in java

```
package com.canopy.template;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.write.*;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;
import jxl.*;


public class rwe{


    public static  void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException, RowsExceededException, WriteException{
        try {

            WritableWorkbook workbook = jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
            System.out.println("Worksheet Created Successfully");
            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet",1);
            Label label = new Label(0, 2, "A l abel record"); 
            sheet.addCell(label); 
            Number number1 = new Number(3, 4, 3.1459); 
            sheet.addCell(number1);
            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Worksheet Creation Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

when i run the code it execute without any problem 
but when i debugg it says

```
The JAR file jxl-2.6.12.jar has no source attachment.
```

[image]

I added jxl-2.6.12.jar in classpath 
I extracted jxl-2.6.12.jar but all the class file are present so there is no source file then why is eclipse asking for source file

It is eclipse luna which i am using for writing code

Comment: You cannot debug a java class which you don't have the source file.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir that's not entirely correct. You can debug it, e.g. read parameter values etc. but it's a pain in the a...

Comment: I was trying to explain what @Thomas already answered.

Answer (score 0):

A normal jar contains the already compiled class files (.class) which are not that human readable. For debugging purposes Eclipse thus tries to resolve the corresponding sources (.java files) that will be displayed instead of the class files when available.

Depending on what build tool you're usign there are different ways of attaching sources. For plain Eclipse you'd have to do it manually, i.e. download the jar which contains the sources (normally named -sources.jar, e.g. [jxl-2.6.12-sources.jar](http://maven.ibiblio.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.12/jxl-2.6.12-sources.jar) and attach it to `jxl-2.6.12.jar`.